# To get unread email from MS Outlook connector in wso2 ei 6.5.0

Tags: outlook, wso2, microsoft-graph-api, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am trying to get Unread email from outlook Inbox by using outlook connector in WSO2 EI 6.5.0. In [Microsoft Graph Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters) it can be possible by using [Query param](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters). When i checked the same in [WSO2 Documenation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+Messages+in+Outlook+Mail) there is no way to give filter option.

```
<outlookmail.getMessageCollectionFromFolder>
            <folderId>Inbox</folderId>
            <q>isRead:false</q> // this option only in gmail connectior            
</outlookmail.getMessageCollectionFromFolder>
```

Is there any possibilities to achieve this? Or Connector needs to be upgraded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because WSO2 [Outlook connector](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Outlook+Mail+Connector) is based on [Outlook REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations) which, as you see is **deprecated**. This connector is not made for handling Microsoft Graph API and won't work.

Comment: Hi @tmoasz,

Thanks for your answer. Is there any other way (eg. calling microsoft API directly instead of using connector etc) to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @tmoasz,
I hope this below Microsoft API i can use directly for my use case(Listmessage,getmessage etc) right ? Awaiting your response.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: @Justin the wso2 connector are quite simple, and if you look close to them, they are just some sequance templates. For example look at this from that "legacy" outlookconnector: https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-connector-outlookmail/blob/master/src/main/resources/config/init.xml You can do very similar things using that Microsoft Graph API